# Pandas populate column 'a' using average of cells directly before and after in column 'b'

Tags: python, pandas, cell, average

I have a time series dataset where GPS is missing for every second time interval.

I'm hoping to use Pandas to fill these missing values using the average of the GPS directly before and after a data gap.

In the example below, it would result in populating columns 'AV_latitude' and 'AV_longitude' at 'timestamp' '06:41:59' with the average of positions directly before and after.

[image]

It's not a problem if all cells in 'AV' columns are populated with the same method as I will use 'fillna' to merge missing data values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a method to deal with `NaN` values, `.fillna`. Among other methods, it supports "forward fill" and "backward fill", a combination of which will give the desired result.

```
df[['lat', 'long']] = (
    df[['lat', 'long']].fillna(method='ffill') 
    + df[['lat', 'long']].fillna(method='backfill')
) / 2
```

As a bonus, this will also take care of multiple consecutive `NaN`s

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you what you really want to is thake the `mean` OR what you actually want to do is resample the data. The latter would be a more common task, generally speaking. Here is the input data I used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': {0: '6/16/2020 6:41:58', 1: '6/16/2020 6:42:00'},'latitude': {0: -32.4353472, 1: -32.43535107}})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df

    timestamp           latitude
0   2020-06-16 06:41:58 -32.435347
1   2020-06-16 06:42:00 -32.435351
```

Then, resample the data:

```
df = df.resample('s', on='timestamp').mean().reset_index()
df
```

output:

```
    timestamp            latitude
0   2020-06-16 06:41:58  -32.435347
1   2020-06-16 06:41:59  NaN
2   2020-06-16 06:42:00  -32.435351
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for helping me out. That's a cool function and I'll likely have many uses for it but it doesn't fix the issue I'm having here. I do have data at that timestamp, just not a GPS lat/long. I'm hoping to create an averaged position to give consisted spacial context to all data points. Cheers